# How to merge two list of strings with multiple character replacements

Tags: python, string, list, loops, replace

I have two lists of strings.

```
A = ['HKO', 'HKO', 'HKO'] 
B = ['12M', 'M4M', 'MKO']
```

I want to merge them such that the result is:

```
C = ['HKM', 'MKM', 'MKO']
```

That is, if there is an `'M'` in list `B`, I want to keep it, else I want to replace it with the value in that index of A.

What is the best way to do this? The problem I keep encountering is B's `'M4M'` such that I'm unable to replace both the `'H'` and the `'O'`. For example I'll get:

```
['HKM', 'MKO', 'HKM']
```

Thanks. (The code I have so far is below!)

```
replace_list = [(0, 2), (1, 0), (1, 2), (2, 0)]

list = []
for i in range(len(mix_list)):
    for j in range(len(letters)):
        if j != replace_list[i][1]:
            list.append(letters[i][j])
        else:
            list.append('M')
    list_join = ("".join(list))

    print list
print "join", list_join
```

where I get: join HKMMKOHKM

Comment: Show your code that's getting the wrong answer, and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: It sounds like you're just not indexing all the string characters correctly. Don't make the mistake of using `string.index('M')`, since that will only find the first occurrence.

Comment: What are `mix_list` and `letters`? How does `replace_list` fit into this?

Comment: The original question doesn't mention a list of tuples, just two lists of strings.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function `map()` with the helper function `func()`:

```
A = ['HKO', 'HKO', 'HKO']
B = ['12M', 'M4M', 'MKO']

def func(a, b):
    if 'M' in b:
        m = map(lambda x, y:
            y if y == 'M' else x, a, b)
        return ''.join(m)
    else:
        return a

list(map(func, A, B))
# ['HKM', 'MKM', 'MKO']
```

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with `zip`s and `map`s

```
f = lambda s: ''.join([a if b !='M' else b for a, b in s])
list(map(f, (map(lambda k: zip(*k), zip(A,B)))))
```

Outputs

```
['HKM', 'MKM', 'MKO']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `zip` and `str.join`:

```
A = ['HKO', 'HKO', 'HKO'] 
B = ['12M', 'M4M', 'MKO']
result = [''.join(d if d == 'M' else c for c, d in zip(a, b)) for a, b in zip(A, B)]
```

Output:

```
['HKM', 'MKM', 'MKO']
```